# Error invalid conversion from 'char' to 'est*' -fpermissive

Tags: c++, insert

Es mi primera vez en este sitio, entonces, ¡aquí vamos!. He estado tratando de resolver este error, pero no he encontrado la manera. Este es el código completo. El error aparece en la línea 44. El programa es sobre añadir N números de estudiantes y organizarlos por su peso mediante el método de inserción.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
struct Estudiante{ //Estructura que almacenará los datos de los estudiantes
    char nomb;
    float peso;
};
Estudiante *est = new Estudiante[100]; //Puntero para añadir nuevo estudiante
void Insercion(int total, struct est* nomb, struct est* peso){ //Aplicación del método de inserción
    int i,aux;
    for(i = 0; i < total; i++){
        aux = est[i].peso;
        while((i > 0) && (est[i-1].peso > aux)){
            est[i] = est[i-1];
            i--;
        }
        est[i].peso = aux;
    }
}
void Mostrar(int total){ //Función para mostrar los estudiantes organizados con respecto a su peso
    int i;
    cout<<"Lista de peso de estudiantes:"<<endl<<endl;
    for(i = 0; i < total; i++){
        cout<<"Nombre: "<<est[i].nomb<<endl;
        cout<<"Peso: "<<est[i].peso<<endl<<endl;
    }
}

int main(){ //Función principal del programa, donde se añaden nuevos estudiantes, se ordenan y se muestran
    int i, total;
    cout<<"Cuantos estudiantes desea registrar?: ";
    cin>>total;
    cout<<endl;
    do{
        cout<<"**** ESCUELA PUBLICA ****"<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"\tDatos de nuevo estudiante"<<endl;
        cout<<"* Ingrese el nombre: ";
        cin>>est[i].nomb;
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"* Ingrese el peso (kg.): ";
        cin>>est[i].peso;
        cout<<endl;
        Insercion(total,est[i].nomb,est[i].peso);
    }while(i == total);
    Mostrar(total);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tienes tantos errores en el código que no se ni por donde empezar. Lo que si puedo decir es que no se cuál es la línea 44 a la que te refieres y que no me queda claro cuál es la pregunta que estás haciendo.

Comment: La línea 44 es la que dice: Insercion(total,est[i].nomb,est[i].peso); Lo que yo quiero saber es cómo corregir ese error, ya que es el único que obtengo al compilar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es claro y conciso. Tal vez no lo entiendas por estar en inglés, te lo traduzco:

> ```
> Error invalid conversion from 'char' to 'est*'
> ```

> ```
> Error conversión no válida de 'char' a 'est*'
> ```

Sucede al llamar a la función `Insercion`:

```
Insercion(total,est[i].nomb,est[i].peso);
```

Cuya firma es:

```
Insercion(int total, struct est* nomb, struct est* peso)
```

- Primer parámetro, de tipo `int`.
- Segundo parámetro, de tipo `struct est*`.
- Tercer parámetro, de tipo `struct est*`.

¿Con qué parámetros la estás llamando?

```
//                             char
//                      /‾‾‾‾‾
//                      |
//                 vvvvvvvvvvv
   Insercion(total,est[i].nomb,est[i].peso);
//           ^^^^^             ^^^^^^^^^^^
//             |                    |
//              \___ int             \_____ float
```

El segundo y tercer parámetro son incompatibles con el tipo definido en la firma de la función pues el segundo parámetro espera un `struct est*` y le pasas un `char` mientras que el tercer parámetro espera un `struct est*` y le pasas un `float`.